# How can one rollback commands in Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo

Ben Alex has a [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/benalexau/introduction-to-spring-roo-100-2805183) introducing Spring Roo.

On slide 8, there is the claim "Even if you make a mistake, Roo will rollback changes!"

I'm unable to find actual documentation of this feature.  Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you typed in a command you cannot rollback using roo command line(as far as I know)

Comment: I dont have any pointers to documentation I am just telling from my working knowledge..

Comment: I think the claim refers to the atomic nature of Roo commands, that they do not leave your application in an incomplete state.

Comment: plz view this http://twitter.com/schmidtstefan/status/17472999685
Reply to my tweet by @schmidtstefan

Answer (score 2):

You cannot roll back, but roo keeps a log, roo.log, so you can repeat everything you've done up until then. And of course, you can just remove what's been added from your source, and usually Roo will update the source for you

Answer (score 1):

You can't roll back, you can keep a backup using the command

```
perform backup
```

on your Spring Roo console, or better yet -- use a version control system like Mercurial.

Comment: Of course version control was being used, but this is only as granular as the commits. (And it certainly wasn't within my control to change to a DVCS.)

Comment: Then you probably will have to go ahead with `perform backup` as for now.