# How to rollback commands in Spring Roo?

Tags: java, spring-roo

I realise that [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149715/how-can-one-rollback-commands-in-spring-roo) but the thread seems about 9 months old. Just want to check if the newer versions have added this capability.

I seemed to have goofed up with one command and desperately want to rollback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are still working on this: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-911

This feature will solve this problem by optionally keeping everything in a local git repo (so you can always roll back to the last version).

**Update:** From the JIRA comments, it seems like a first working version is available

Comment: Thanks Sean - just checked the JIRA link. Its been outstanding for a while!

Comment: @Nilesh I know, but that's the status. Other similar requests have been closed as dupes: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1015 , https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1124

Comment: @MikeR perhaps. haven't looked at roo in more than 3 years

Answer (score 0):

OK- I have used Refactoring from STS to make the change and ROO Shell did pick this up and made corresponding changes to ROO artifacts.

I was running ROO shell from within STS.

If that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

As @sean-patrick-floyd mentioned, this is now available as a Spring Roo 'addon'.

Description: Offers GIT Integration in the project. Each successfully executed command will be automatically committed to a local GIT repository.

```
roo > addon search git
roo > addon install id --searchResult 1
```

Then you can use the built in commands to rollback:

```
* git revert commit
* git revert last
```